# Is it possible to get audio from an ICY stream with percentage and seek function

Tags: ios, audio-streaming, percentage, seek, internet-radio

I'm trying to reproduce audio from an ICY stream. I'm able to reproduce that with AVPlayer and some good open source library but I'm not able to control the stream. I have no idea how I can get the percentage reproduced or how to seek to a specific time in the stream. Is that possible? Is there a good library that can help me? 
Actually I'm using [AFSoundManager](https://github.com/AlvaroFranco/AFSoundManager) but I'm always receiving negative numbers for percentage and I get invalid time when trying to seek the stream at a specified time.

That's the code that I'm using:

```
AFSoundManager.sharedManager().startStreamingRemoteAudioFromURL("http://www.abstractpath.com/files/audiosamples/sample.mp3") { (percentage, elapsedTime, timeRemaining, error, poppi) in

        if error == nil {
            //This block will be fired when the audio progress increases in 1%
            if elapsedTime > 0 {
                println(elapsedTime)
                self.slider.value = Float(elapsedTime*1000)
            }
        } else {
        //Handle the error
            println(error)
        }
```

I'm able of course to get the elapsedTime but not the percentage or the remainingTime. I always get negative numbers.
This code works perfectly with remote or local audio file but not with the stream.

Comment: Please show some code.

Comment: I added the code but I don't think it could help. I'm not interesting to use exactly this code. I just want to know if it is possible to control the stream. Even with other library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't possible.

These streams are live.  There is nothing to seek to because what you haven't heard hasn't happened yet.  Even streams that playback music end-to-end are still "live" in the sense that the audio you haven't received hasn't been encoded yet.  (Small codec and transit buffers aside, of course.)